# How to turn my OLED display on my Raspberry Pi on?

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I want to start making some Rapsberry Pi projects as a beginner and recently bought [this](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/2.23inch_OLED_HAT) display, but cannot seem to get it on. Could somebody provide me with some Python code to make it say **Hello World!** for example?

Or maybe better, direct me to some documentation which helps me? I cannot seem to find anything useful and I am still too noob to understand the documentation provided on the page I linked above.

Answer (score 1):

My first try would be the adafruit library
https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_DisplayIO_SSD1305

You may find installing the dependencies a little trying the first time unless you already have that but there is enough documentation to be found to make it work - linked from the github page I've shared